# how to store form-data in multiple tabs?

Tags: angularjs

Tab object contain 6 tabs I want to store data each tab by selecting tab and assigning to form data inside selected tab.

I achieved by selected tab and assigning form data into selected tab. Here is the problem if selected tab6 assigned form data then I selected tab5 assign form data to tab5 on submited form tab6 data is not visible but last selected tab values only visible.

Tried code:

```
<form>
    <h4 id="numberOfTabsLabel">How many tabs you want to add</h4>
    <select id="numberOfTabs" ng-model="tabProp.name" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in items" ng-change="changeProp(tabProp.name)">
      <option value="" selected>Select a Number</option>
    </select>
<h4 id="numberOfTabsLabel4">You have selected <span id="no_of_tab">{{tabProperty}}</span> tabs. <br/>
<span class="asign"> Select the option to Assign tab properties</span></h4>
<select id="tabProperties" ng-model="tabContent">
  <option value=" " selected>Select a Tab</option>
  <option value="{{$index+1}}" ng-repeat="i in getNumber(tabProp.name)"><span>{{$index+1}}</span></option>
</select>
<span>Tab Heading:<input type="text" value="" ng-model="layoutObj.tab_name" size="40" id="tab_name" name="tab_name"></span>
<input type="button" ng-click="layoutSubmit($event, tabProp.name, tabContent, hooks)" value="save" size="40" id="{{0+tabContent}}" class="ibm-btn-pri ibm-btn-blue-50" name="first_name">
```

```
<script>
app.controller("mainCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
  {id: 1, name: '1'}, 
  {id: 2,name: '2' }, 
  {id: 3,name: '3' },
  {id: 4,name: '4' }, 
  {id: 5, name: '5'},
  {id: 6,name: '6'}
  ];

  $scope.changeProp = function(val) {
    debugger;
    $scope.tabProperty = val;
  }
  $scope.getNumber = function(n) {
    debugger;
    var tempArray = new Array(n);
    console.log(n + "--" + tempArray);
    return tempArray;
  };
  $scope.layoutSubmit = function(event, ntabs, ctab, nhooks, targethook) {
    var layoutFormValues = $scope.layoutObj;
    cTab = "tab" + ctab,
      $scope[cTab] = {};

    $scope.tabs = {};
    for (var i = 1; i <= ntabs; i++) {
      var tab = "tab" + i;
      var tabs = "tab" + i;
      $scope.tabs[tab] = $scope[tab];
    }
    $scope.tabs[cTab] = layoutFormValues;
    $scope.proj = $scope.tabs;
    console.log($scope.proj);
  }
});
</script>
```

Check out the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a0pL9wr6/25/)

Comment: check out the fiddle is not working?

Comment: not working can you help please?

Comment: 1) if select tab5  tab heading " tab5"  clicked save 
2) next i will select tab4 tab heading is "tab4" click save 
 my pro object contain 

Object
tab1
:
undefined
tab2
:
undefined
tab3
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
tab4
:
Object
__proto__
:
Object
tab5
:
Object
tab_name
:
"tab5"

Comment: please help me how to store all data